# Delphi android show combobox list programmatically

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey

How to show combobox list programmatically without clicking on it on Android mobile application? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DropDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomComboBox.DropDown) method.

```
MyComboBox.DropDown();
```